# Sidebar does not show widgets but individual sidebar content

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming, sidebar

My dynamic sidebar does not show standard widgets like recent posts or archives but the individual content I put into the sidebar.php

This is the sidebar-part from my functions.php:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_register_sidebars' );

function my_register_sidebars() {

    register_sidebar( array(
    'name'         => __( 'Primäre Sidebar' ),
    'id'           => 'sidebar-main',
    'description'  => __( 'Rechte Hauptsidebar für Werbeflächen und Meta' ),
    'before_title' => '<h4>',
    'after_title'  => '</h4>',
) );
```

and this is the code from sidebar.php:

```
<aside id="sidebar-main">
<div id="widgetarea">

<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar() ) : endif; ?>

<h4>TESTESTEST</h4>
<p>HALLOHALLO</p>

</div>
</aside>
```

As always, I call the sidebar by `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` in my theme.

How come the other stuff is being displayed but not the widgets? I have no clue.
Edit: I already tried deactivating plugins - no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to your sidebar is wrong. This

```
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar() ) : endif; ?>
```

should be

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-main' ) ) : ?>

        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-main' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Wow. I was looking at it a thousand times and did not notice that. Thank you, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

try this in sidebar.php:

```
<aside id="sidebar-main">
<div id="widgetarea">

    <?php dynamic_sidebar('Primäre Sidebar') ?>

</div>
</aside>
```